# Which list item is the most common

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to find the most common list item common([b,a,a,a,c,d,b,f,s,f,s,f,s,f,s,f,f],R) so the result should be R=f,
I was thinking if we take the list , go to the end of the list take el=b ,num1=1 then go back to the beginning and compare if b=b ,num1=num1+1 else a!=b then if num2=num2+1 , num1>num2 recursion else el=a or something like this, but i had some difficulty transforming it into Prolog.

insert_sort sorts the list , but for  some interesting reason if i use `las(X,Y)` (I override the original `last/2` ) I get 4-a if I use `last(X,Y)` i get just a...

```
most_common([X|Y],J):-
    insert_sort([X|Y],[R|Rs]),             
    count_runs([R|Rs],G),
    las(G,J).

las([N-Y],Y).
las([_|T],Y):- las(T,Y).
las([_|Tail], Y) :- las(Tail, Y).

insert_sort(List,Sorted):-
   i_sort(List,[],Sorted).

i_sort([],Acc,Acc).
i_sort([H|T],Acc,Sorted):- 
    insert(H,Acc,NAcc),
    i_sort(T,NAcc,Sorted).

insert(X,[],[X]).     
insert(X,[Y|T],[Y|NT]):- X @> Y, insert(X,T,NT).
insert(X,[Y|T],[X,Y|T]):- X @=< Y.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like homework, so I'm not going to give you a full answer, but will suggest how you could solve it in one particular way, which isn't necessarily the best way:

- Sort the list into sorted order (by standard order of terms if this is good enough): look at [`sort/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2) routines. e.g., `[b,a,a,a,c,d,b]` becomes `[a,a,a,b,b,c,d]`.
- Take the sorted list and count the size of 'runs', perhaps to convert `[a,a,a,b,b,c,d]` into `[3-a,2-b,1-c,1-d]` (where `-`/2 is simply another term). e.g., consider the following code:

---

```
count_runs([E|Es], C) :-
      % defer to count_runs/3 with an initial count of element E
    count_runs(Es, 1-E, C).

  % return the final count for Y elements if none remain (base case)
count_runs([], N-Y, [N-Y]). 

count_runs([X|Es], N-Y, [N-Y|Rest]) :-
      % if X is not equal to Y, record the count and continue next run
    X \== Y, !,  
    count_runs([X|Es], Rest).

count_runs([_X|Es], N-Y, Rest) :-
      % else X equals Y; increment the counter and continue
    NPlusOne is N + 1,
    count_runs(Es, NPlusOne-Y, Rest).
```

---

- Perform something like [`keysort/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=keysort/2) to order the terms by the value of their keys (i.e., the numbers which are the counts, turning `[3-a,2-b,1-c,1-d]` into `[1-c,1-d,2-b,3-a]`). Then, the most-occurring elements of the list are the values at the end of the list with the same key value (i.e., here, this is the `a` in the last term `3-a`). In general, they may be more than one element that occurs the most (equally with another).

Good luck.

Comment: most_common([a,a,b,f,f,d,f,s,d,s,d,s,d,s],E).
E = f .

Comment: This is the part for complete code:                                                        most_common([X|Y],C):- count_runs([X|Y],K),last(K,C).     %so we have sorted list K and using Last() we find the letter
                                                                               
last([N-Y], Y).
last([_|Tail], Y) :- last(Tail, Y).

But lets say we have a list like this: 
 
most_common([a,a,b,f,f,d,f,s,d,s,d,s,d,s],E). -> last([1-b, 1-f, 1-s, 1-f, 1-s, 1-f, 1-s, ... - ...|...], a) and the most common item is a but not f so we have a small problem :D

Comment: A small optimisation to the overall problem would be to define `count_runs/2` such that it accumulates item counts in reverse order, ordering them into greatest-to-smallest counts, resulting in the most occurring element `E` in the head of the resultant list, i.e., `[_-E|_]`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Prolog lambdas](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord), we use the meta-predicates [`tcount/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29960878/4609915) and [`reduce/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30706698/4609915), as well as the reified term equality predicate [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915):

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

mostcommon_in(E,Xs) :-
   tcount(=(E),Xs,M),
   maplist(Xs+\X^N^(tcount(=(X),Xs,N)),Xs,Counts),
   reduce(\C0^C1^C^(C is max(C0,C1)),Counts,M).
```

Sample query:

```
?- mostcommon_in(X,[a,b,c,d,a,b,c,a,b]).
X = a ;
X = b ;
false.
```

Note that this is **monotone** (unlike it's earlier quick-hack version). Look!

```
?- mostcommon_in(X,[A,B,C,D,A,B,C,A,B]), A=a,B=b,C=c,D=d.
X = a, A = a, B = b, C = c, D = d ;
X = b, A = a, B = b, C = c, D = d ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

Preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) by 
using [`list_counts/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30027124/4609915) for defining `mostcommonitem_in/2` as follows:

```
mostcommonitem_in(E,Xs) :-
   list_counts(Xs,Cs),                      % tag items with multiplicity
   maplist(\ (X-N)^(M-X)^(M is -N),Cs,Ps),  % prepare keysorting
   keysort(Ps,[Max-_|_]),                   % sort ascending by negated count
   member(Max-E,Ps).                        % pick most common ones
```

Let's run a query!

```
?- mostcommonitem_in(X,[a,b,c,d,a,b,c,a,b]).
X = a ;
X = b ;
false.                                % OK
```

But, is it still monotone?

```
?- mostcommonitem_in(X,[A,B,C,D,A,B,C,A,B]), A=a,B=b,C=c,D=d.
X = A, A = a, B = b, C = c, D = d ;
X = B, B = b, A = a, C = c, D = d ;
false.                                % OK: monotone
```

Got speed? (compared to the pure answer I showed in [my previous answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30852278/4609915))

```
% OLD
?- length(Xs,5), time(findall(t,mostcommon_in(E,Xs),Ts)), length(Ts,N_sols).
% 854,636 inferences,    0.115 CPU in 0.115 seconds (100% CPU, 7447635 Lips)
N_sols = 71,   Xs = [_,_,_,_,_],     Ts = [t,t,t|...].    
?- length(Xs,6), time(findall(t,mostcommon_in(E,Xs),Ts)), length(Ts,N_sols).
% 4,407,975 inferences,  0.449 CPU in 0.449 seconds (100% CPU, 9813808 Lips)
N_sols = 293,  Xs = [_,_,_,_,_,_],   Ts = [t,t,t|...].
?- length(Xs,7), time(findall(t,mostcommon_in(E,Xs),Ts)), length(Ts,N_sols).
% 24,240,240 inferences, 2.385 CPU in 2.384 seconds (100% CPU, 10162591 Lips)
N_sols = 1268, Xs = [_,_,_,_,_,_,_], Ts = [t,t,t|...].

% NEW
?- length(Xs,5), time(findall(t,mostcommonitem_in(E,Xs),Ts)), length(Ts,N_sols).
% 4,031 inferences, 0.001 CPU in  0.002 seconds (93% CPU, 2785423 Lips)
N_sols = 71,   Xs = [_,_,_,_,_],     Ts = [t,t,t|...].    
?- length(Xs,6), time(findall(t,mostcommonitem_in(E,Xs),Ts)), length(Ts,N_sols).
% 17,632 inferences, 0.002 CPU in 0.002 seconds (100% CPU, 9194323 Lips)
N_sols = 293,  Xs = [_,_,_,_,_,_],   Ts = [t,t,t|...].    
?- length(Xs,7), time(findall(t,mostcommonitem_in(E,Xs),Ts)), length(Ts,N_sols).
% 82,263 inferences, 0.023 CPU in 0.023 seconds (100% CPU, 3540609 Lips)
N_sols = 1268, Xs = [_,_,_,_,_,_,_], Ts = [t,t,t|...].
```

Comment: `counts_flipped/2`: oh these manual `maplist` and λ-compilers.

Answer (score -2):

I could give you a high-level answer: You could sort the list and then it's relatively easy to count the items, one after another, and update what so far is the most common item.