# Repeated elements in a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I would like to find a method to find the most repeated element in a list if two elements repeat the same number of times. I want the predicate to be a list that contains both elements. How can I do that?

Sample queries and expected answers:

```
?- maxRepeated([1,3,3,4,2,2],X).
X = [3,2].

% common case: there is one element that is the most repeated
?- maxRepeated([1,3,3,3,3,4,2,2],X).
X = [3].

% all elements repeat the same number of times
?- maxRepeated([1,3,4,2],X).
X = [1,3,4,2].
```

I have the same problem with the less repeated element.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Have you made any attempts at a solution? Also, are repeated elements always contiguous? For example, what about `[1,3,2,1,3,3,1,4,1]`?

Comment: It is a proyect I am trying to develop and in it is based in some things related to what I have seen in class. I know how to get only one result, but not a list, and I don't know how to do it. And no, the elements are not always continuous. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @user3657716 did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The predicate `mostcommonitems_in/2` (to be presented in this answer) bears more than a little resemblance to 
`mostcommonitem_in/2`, [defined in one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30856357/4609915).

In the following we use [`list_counts/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30027124/4609915), [Prolog lambdas](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord), [`foldl/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4), [`tchoose/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30953695/4609915), and [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915):

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

mostcommonitems_in(Ms,Xs) :-
   list_counts(Xs,Cs),
   foldl(\ (_-N)^M0^M1^(M1 is max(M0,N)),Cs,0,M),
   tchoose(\ (E-N)^E^(N=M), Cs,Ms).
```

Let's run some queries!

First, the three queries given by the OP:

```
?- mostcommonitems_in(Xs,[1,3,3,4,2,2]).
Xs = [3,2].

?- mostcommonitems_in(Xs,[1,3,3,3,3,4,2,2]).
Xs = [3].

?- mostcommonitems_in(Xs,[1,3,4,2]).
Xs = [1,3,4,2].
```

Alright! Some more ground queries---hat tip to @lurker and @rpax:

```
?- mostcommonitems_in(Xs,[1,3,2,1,3,3,1,4,1]).
Xs = [1].

?- mostcommonitems_in(Xs,[1,3,3,4,3,2]).
Xs = [3].

?- mostcommonitems_in(Xs,[1,2,3,4,5,6]).
Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6].

?- mostcommonitems_in(Xs,[1,3,3,4,2,3,2,2]).
Xs = [3,2].
```

OK! How about *three items* each of which occurs exactly three times in the list?

```
?- mostcommonitems_in(Xs,[a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,x,d,e]).
Xs = [a,b,c].                                          % works as expected
```

How about the following *somewhat more general* query?

```
?- mostcommonitems_in(Xs,[A,B,C]).
  Xs = [C]    ,     A=B           ,     B=C
; Xs = [B]    ,     A=B           , dif(B,C)
; Xs = [C]    ,               A=C , dif(B,C)
; Xs = [C]    ,           dif(A,C),     B=C
; Xs = [A,B,C], dif(A,B), dif(A,C), dif(B,C).
```

Above query breaks almost all impure codes... Our Prolog code is **pure**, so we're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about prolog, and probably there's a way to do this better, but here's a working solution: (SWI prolog)

```
%List of tuples, keeps track of the number of repetitions.
modify([],X,[(X,1)]).
modify([(X,Y)|Xs],X,[(X,K)|Xs]):- K is Y+1.
modify([(Z,Y)|Xs],X,[(Z,Y)|K]):- Z =\= X, modify(Xs,X,K).

highest((X1,Y1),(_,Y2),(X1,Y1)):- Y1 >= Y2.
highest((_,Y1),(X2,Y2),(X2,Y2)):- Y2 > Y1.

maxR([X],X).
maxR([X|Xs],K):- maxR(Xs,Z),highest(X,Z,K).

rep([],R,R).
rep([X|Xs],R,R1):-modify(R,X,R2),rep(Xs,R2,R1).

maxRepeated(X,R):- rep(X,[],K),maxR(K,R).


?- maxRepeated([1,3,3,4,3,2] ,X).
X = (3, 3) .

?- maxRepeated([1,2,3,4,5,6] ,X).
X = (1, 1) .
```

The less repeated element is analogous.

I think that is better to use tuples in this case, but changing the result into a list shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This solution does not satisfies the requirement: `maxRepeated([1,3,3,4,2,2] ,X). X=[3,2]`

Comment: _but changing the result into a list shouldn't be a problem_. (3,2) into [3,2] it's a trivial operation.

Comment: You copy my answer and you downvote it. Where's your imagination? Where's your creativity? I've never met a person like you in SO.

Comment: No,  downvoter is not me. I have too little reputation. For downvote need to have 125.

Answer (score -3):

There is my solution on Visual Prolog:

```
domains
value=integer
tuple=t(value,integer)
list=value*
tuples=tuple*

predicates
modify(tuples,value,tuples)
highest(tuple,tuple,tuple)
maxR(tuples,integer,integer)
maxR(tuples,integer)
rep(list,tuples,tuples)
maxRepeated(list,list)
filter(tuples,integer,list)

clauses
modify([],X,[t(X,1)]):- !.
modify([t(X,Y)|Xs],X,[t(X,K)|Xs]):- K = Y+1, !.
modify([t(Z,Y)|Xs],X,[t(Z,Y)|K]):- Z <> X, modify(Xs,X,K).

highest(t(X1,Y1),t(_,Y2),t(X1,Y1)):- Y1 >= Y2, !.
highest(t(_,Y1),t(X2,Y2),t(X2,Y2)):- Y2 > Y1.

maxR([],R,R):- !.
maxR([t(_,K)|Xs],Rs,R):- K>Rs,!, maxR(Xs,K,R).
maxR([_|Xs],Rs,R):- maxR(Xs,Rs,R).
maxR(X,R):- maxR(X,0,R).

rep([],R,R).
rep([X|Xs],R,R1):-modify(R,X,R2),rep(Xs,R2,R1).

filter([],_,[]):-!.
filter([t(X,K)|Xs],K,[X|FXs]):- !, filter(Xs,K,FXs).
filter([_|Xs],K,FXs):- filter(Xs,K,FXs).

maxRepeated(X,RL):- rep(X,[],Reps),maxR(Reps,K),filter(Reps,K,RL).

goal
maxRepeated([1,3,3,4,2,3,2,2] ,X),
maxRepeated([1,2,3,4,5,6] ,Y).
```

Comment: It seems that it's my answer, but more verbose. Don't you think? Even the clauses' names are common.

Comment: I think so, and don't hide it. But my version solves the problem voiced in question, unlike yours. I took your code and while I made it work on Visual Prolog I implemented desired algorithm.