# How to check which items on the list meet certain condition?

Tags: prolog

How to make a function called busLineLonger, which receives at least two parameters to decide if a bus line is longer or not?

```
*/This is how it works*/
* busStops(number_of_the_bus,number_of_stops)*/

/*?- busLineLonger([busStops(1,7),busStops(2,4),busStops(3,6)],5,WHICH).
* WHICH = [1,3].
```

Using only comparative things, like @> <@ /==@.
Sorry my english

Edit...
So far I've think of something like this

```
busLineLonger([busStops(A,B)|R],N,[_|_]):-
   N@>B,
   busLineLonger(R,N,A).
```

Comment: So.. how would *you* this? And why do you think it is not good enough?

Comment: I've edited with something I thought, Eugene.

Comment: Have you looked up the difference between `@>` and `>` in the Prolog documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could do it using [meta-predicates](/questions/tagged/meta-predicates),
[reified test predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13664870/4609915),
and [lambda expressions](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord).

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
```

First, we define the reified test predicate `(>)/3` like this:

```
>(X,Y,Truth) :- (X > Y -> Truth=true ; Truth=false).
```

Next, we define *three* different implementations of `busLineLonger/3` (named `busLineLonger1/3`, `busLineLonger2/3`, and `busLineLonger3/3`) in terms of the following meta-predicates: `maplist/3`, `tfilter/3`, `tfiltermap/4`, and `tchoose/3`. Of course, in the end we will only need *one*---but that shouldn't keep us from exploring the various options we have!

#### #1: based on [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211229/4609915) and [`maplist/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915)

Do two separate steps: 
 1. Select items of concern.
 2. Project those items to the data of interest.

```
busLineLonger1(Ls0,N,IDs) :-
    tfilter(\busStops(_,L)^(L>N), Ls0,Ls1),
    maplist(\busStops(Id,_)^Id^true, Ls1, IDs).
```

#### #2: based on `tfiltermap/4`

Here, we use exactly the same lambda expressions as before, but we pass 
them *both* to meta-predicate `tfiltermap/4`. Doing so can help reduce
save some resources.

```
busLineLonger2(Ls,N,IDs) :-
    tfiltermap(\busStops(_,L)^(L>N), \busStops(Id,_)^Id^true, Ls,IDs).
```

Here's how `tfiltermap/4` can be implemented:

```
:- meta_predicate tfiltermap(2,2,?,?).
tfiltermap(Filter_2,Map_2,Xs,Ys) :-
   list_tfilter_map_list(Xs,Filter_2,Map_2,Ys).

:- meta_predicate list_tfilter_map_list(?,2,2,?).
list_tfilter_map_list([],_,_,[]).
list_tfilter_map_list([X|Xs],Filter_2,Map_2,Ys1) :-
   if_(call(Filter_2,X), (call(Map_2,X,Y),Ys1=[Y|Ys0]), Ys1=Ys0),
   list_tfilter_map_list(Xs,Filter_2,Map_2,Ys0).
```

#### #3: based on `tchoose/3`

Here we do not use two separate lambda expressions, but a combined one.

```
busLineLonger3(Ls,N,IDs) :-
    tchoose(\busStops(Id,L)^Id^(L>N), Ls,IDs).
```

Here's how `tchoose/3` can be implemented:

```
:- meta_predicate tchoose(3,?,?).
tchoose(P_3,Xs,Ys) :-
   list_tchoose_list(Xs,P_3,Ys).

:- meta_predicate list_tchoose_list(?,3,?).
list_tchoose_list([],_,[]).
list_tchoose_list([X|Xs],P_3,Ys1) :-
   if_(call(P_3,X,Y), Ys1=[Y|Ys0], Ys1=Ys0),
   list_tchoose_list(Xs,P_3,Ys0).
```

---

Let's see them in action!

```
?- Xs = [busStops(1,7),busStops(2,4),busStops(3,6)], busLineLonger1(Xs,5,Zs).
Xs = [busStops(1, 7), busStops(2, 4), busStops(3, 6)],
Zs = [1, 3].

?- Xs = [busStops(1,7),busStops(2,4),busStops(3,6)], busLineLonger2(Xs,5,Zs).
Xs = [busStops(1, 7), busStops(2, 4), busStops(3, 6)],
Zs = [1, 3].

?- Xs = [busStops(1,7),busStops(2,4),busStops(3,6)], busLineLonger3(Xs,5,Zs).
Xs = [busStops(1, 7), busStops(2, 4), busStops(3, 6)],
Zs = [1, 3].
```

---

*Done!*

So... what's **the bottom line**?

- Many meta-predicates are versatile and can be used in a lot of sitations similar to the one here.
- Implementing these meta-predicates is a one time effort that is amortized quickly.
- Many meta-predicates handle the "recursive part", which enables you to focus on actual work.
- Often, with meta-predicates (as with regular ones), "there's more than one way to do things".

  - Depending on the concrete circumstances, using a particular meta-predicate may be better than using another one, and vice versa.
  - For this question, I think, implementation #3 (the one using `tchoose/3`) is best.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to fix in your code:

- 3rd argument is `[_|_]`, that is the result are free variables... doesn't make sense. You need two cases: one in which the `B` is greater than `N` and you include the result; the other in which `B` is less or equal than `N`, and you don't include that result.
- base case is missing. what's the result when bus list is empty?

A possible solution:

```
busLineLonger([],_,[]).
busLineLonger([busStops(A,B)|R],N,[A|S]) :- B>N, busLineLonger(R,N,S).
busLineLonger([busStops(_,B)|R],N,S) :- B=<N, busLineLonger(R,N,S).
```

---

```
?- busLineLonger([busStops(1,7),busStops(2,4),busStops(3,6)],5,WHICH).
WHICH = [1, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, mescalinum! That was what I was looking for. I'm fairly new in Prolog language, and your explanation helped me. Thanks again!